# jQuery REST POST JSON List<Object>

Tags: c#, javascript, jquery, json, asp.net-web-api

I'm having the following classes on C#:

```
public class Record
{
    public Record()
    {
       this.Artists = new List<Artist>();       
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public List<Artist> Artists { get; set; }
}

public class Artist
{
    public Artist()
    {
       this.Songs = new List<Song>();       
    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Album { get; set; }
    public List<Song> Songs { get; set; }
}

public class Song
{
    public Song()
    {

    }

    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }        
}
```

Then we add some data:

```
Record record = new Record();
record.Id = 1;
record.Name = "Some music";
record.Description = "Something...";


Artist artist = new Artist();
artist.Id = 1;
artist.Name = "Bob Marley";
artist.Album = "Legend";

Song song = new Song();
song.Id = 1;
song.Name = "No woman no cry";
artist.Songs.Add(song);

song = new Song();
song.Id = 2;
song.Name = "Could you be loved";
artist.Songs.Add(song);
record.Artists.Add(artist);

artist = new Artist();
artist.Id = 2;
artist.Name = "Major Lazer";
artist.Album = "Free the universe";

song = new Song();
song.Id = 2;
song.Name = "Get free";
artist.Songs.Add(song);

song = new Song();
song.Id = 2;
song.Name = "Watch out for this";
artist.Songs.Add(song);
record.Artists.Add(artist);

string jsonVal = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(record);
textBox1.Text = jsonVal;
```

The last 2 lines will serialize the record type object to JSON using Newtonsoft Json and here is the resulted JSON:

```
{"Id":1,"Name":"Some music","Description":"Something...","Artists":[{"Id":1,"Name":"Bob Marley","Album":"Legend","Songs":[{"Id":1,"Name":"No woman no cry"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Could you be loved"}]},{"Id":2,"Name":"Major Lazer","Album":"Free the universe","Songs":[{"Id":2,"Name":"Get free"},{"Id":2,"Name":"Watch out for this"}]}]}
```

Now I need to create this JSON using javascript and POST that json to WEB API endpoint. What I don't know is how to create the object in javascript.

I know there is JSON.stringify(object) that will serialize the object, but how can I create the List ???

I know I can do something like this:

```
var record = 
{
  Name: "Whatever",
  Description: "Something else",

  //How can I make the List<object>      
};
```

I'm thinking about array and probably this is the right one ... something like this:

```
var record = 
{
  Name: "Whatever",
  Description: "Something else",
  Artists: 
  {
     "Name": "Artist Name",
     "Album": "Some Album".
     "Songs":
     {
        "Name": "SongName"
     }
  },      
};
```

and last:

```
JSON.stringify(record);
```

Comment: What is the problem with lists?

Comment: Well I need to create that JSON example (in that format) using JavaScript. The result will be posted to ASP.NET Web API endpoint and will be casted as Record object type. And I don't know how to create the equivalent of List<object> from C# in JavaScript ... Example: List<Song> ...

Comment: I'm guessing I have to use arrys for that ... but not sure

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use a JavaScript [`Array`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array) for a .NET collection.

```
var record = {
  name: "Whatever",
  description: "Something else",
  artists: [{
     name: "Artist Name",
     album: "Some Album",
     songs: [{
        name: "Some Song"
     }]
  }]
};
```

Web API will treat the JSON as case insensitive.

Answer (score -1):

You need to use this code for jQuery REST POST JSON List

```
var jsonObj = [];
$.each({ name: "John", lang: "JS" }, function (key,value) {
jsonObj.push(
{
  key: value
});
});
```